# How do you drill in to Google Analytics custom event data?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, business-intelligence, custom-events

What do people use to dig in to Google Analytics data?

For example, I have a web page that tracks a custom event on it.  I'd like to track a couple metrics:

1) What percent of users on that page successfully call the event at least once?

2) How do I see a bucket of the number of times a user called the event while they're on the page (or in a session, whatever), such as:

```
 0 times -> 800 visitors
 1 times -> 200 visitors
 2 times -> 150 visitors
 etc
```

Ideally I'd get this data emailed to me on a regular basis, maybe with a chart for the second part. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that the event is a Video Play.

You must keep track of how many videos the user played. For that create a session cookie with that number, and increment it at each video play.

Then you can fire a CustomVariable (Page Scoped) to send the number of events the user performed at that page.

Something like this:

> window.onunload = function(){_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Video Plays', cookie_value, 3]);}

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCustomVar

That should get you a nice report